# jquery go to top of div or page after show and hide div

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I have div A with LINK at the bottom (above with many content).
After click the LINK to hide div A and show div B (I use fade in fade out),
the div B not showing/fade in from the beginning of the content, but in the middle where I click for the link.
What can I do to make the it show top of the div or page?

https://jsfiddle.net/5zqcp6gn/

```js
$('.click').click(function() {
  $(".a").fadeOut("slow", function() {
   $(".b").fadeIn("slow");
  });
 });
```

```css
.b {display:none;}
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> </div>

<div class="b">b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br>
</div>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="click">Click</a>
```

Comment: use this jsfiddle better: https://jsfiddle.net/5zqcp6gn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you haven't enabled the jQuery framework in the settings for your fiddle.

[image]

Also you need to change this line:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="click">Click</a>
```

to

```
<a href="#" class="click">Click</a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yz7p73nh/9/

Comment: But I want the div b to fade in fby showing beginning of the content, but not halfway...

Comment: Can you give an example or how you want the content to fade in? this is the documentation for the fadeIn effect by jQuery http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

Comment: just normal fade in. What I mean actually is the div B is showing with the content on bottom, but not from the beginning of div. since my link is at bottom. how can i make it show from the beginning of div B/top of div B?

Comment: .fadeIn() and .fadeOut() is the default, if you want to apply different effects. If you want a slide effect, .slideDown() and .slideUp() might help you. Like so? https://jsfiddle.net/yz7p73nh/12/

Comment: i am not wanting any effect, i already stick with general fade effect.But what I want is the div B show up with its own content on TOP, TOP of the div or TOP of the page.. but not the same place as the link~

Comment: Oh you want it to scroll to the top of `.b` once you click `.click`. Like so https://jsfiddle.net/yz7p73nh/13/?

Comment: Exactly! yes! Thank you~ TT But what if to top without animation?

Comment: Here you go https://jsfiddle.net/yz7p73nh/15/, without animation. Accept and upvote answer if it helped you, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it fades in from the start of the content. I added the same number of "b" as "a".

[Link to jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5zqcp6gn/)

```
<div class="a">a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br>  a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> a<br> </div>

<div class="b">b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br>  b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> </div>
```

Comment: thank you i use your fiddle, hope can find somebody help me

Comment: You press on "Javascript" where you enter javascript code and you select jQuery version so that it is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed Jquery plug-in inclusion if I am not mistaken. Please double check and include it. It will works fine.

Comment: yes, i not sure how to add the plugin, however, it's here:

Comment: Then you just amend div tag as 

<div id='goto_top' class="b">

And,
<a href="#'goto_top" class="click">Click</a>

Comment: Create a dummy anger tag(<a name="top"></a>) before class b div tag and add the below script after (`$(".b").fadeIn("slow");`). This is will work.
`$('#top').animate({
   scrollTop: 0
}, 'slow');`
[Reference](http://jsfiddle.net/syjbT/)